# Get <unknown ssid> when try to retrieve data from connection

Tags: java, android

I think I got a permission problem, can´t get de SSID from the connection.

I tried this way:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid  = (info).getSSID();
TextView ssid_name = findViewById(R.id.SSID_name);
ssid_name.setText(ssid);
```

and this way

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
    String ssid = info.getExtraInfo();
    TextView ssid_name = findViewById(R.id.SSID_name);
    ssid_name.setText(ssid);
}
```

but I'm still getting `<unknown ssid>`.

In the manifest I got this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Are you requesting for coarse location and fine location permissions at runtime? I believe you need this to getSSID()

Comment: That was the problem. Permissions must be explicitly requested from the user

Answer (score 0):

That was the problem. Permissions must be explicitly requested from the user

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE},
            PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
            PERMISSIONS_INTERNET);
```